# Procedural PyQt4 generates extra windows after pyplot.show()

Tags: macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have encountered a strange behaviour on Mac OSX 10.12 when using PyQt4 and matplotlib in a procedural python function.

The function pops up a dialogue which is used to select a directory.  The files in this directory are read, and their data is plotted using matplotlib.pyplot.

The issue is that when matplotlib shows the plot window, additional blank windows are also generated behind the matplotlib window.  These extra windows are only generated if I include the PyQt code in my function.

When I close the matplotlib window the script hangs, and if i close the additional blank windows the function exits without executing the remaining code in the function.

Does anyone else get these extra windows?  I have the feeling that If I can somehow "quit the PyQt app loop" after I've used it to pick my directory then this would fix the problem. This is my intuition / speculation, and attempts to do this have failed.

Here is a screenshot showing the extra windows which pop up when `plt.show()` is called:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

def qt_mpl_test():

    home = os.path.expanduser('~')
    print('Select data top directory...')
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    dat_dir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(w, 'Select data top directory', home)
    dat_dir = str(dat_dir)

    ##  At this stage I load in my data files for processing / plotting
    ##  For the sake of simplicity, generate some data below

    x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

    ax.plot(y, x)

    plt.show()

qt_mpl_test()
```

Comment: Is the code you show the code that produces the undesired behaviour? You're talking about "extra window**s**", but where should more than one window come from?

Comment: Yes, this is the code.  I understand your confusion, it is indeed a very strange behaviour.  I have tested on a Linux machine and this behaviour is specific to my OSX setup.

I have added a screenshot in my original question showing the extra blank windows.